# _context.add not saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a controller which needs to pull the data from the form and add to database. I've done this numerous times before, but for some reason on this specific section of code it will not save at all.

I've got it pulling the info into the console.writeline and checked that it's all the correct info. I have also tried adding dummy data, but nothing will save. I've also tried using just _console.Add();, _console.Add(RACIResUser);, _context.RACIResUser.Add(RACIResUser), but nothing is saving. As I said, I can view it all the correct info in the console, and other parts of the form on the page are saving to a different table within the database, it's just this section that wont save.

Code is below: 
Post Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> InstanceProcess(string InstanceId, [Bind(Prefix="SectionInfo")]IEnumerable<ProcessOutput> secinf)
{
        var res = (from i in _context.SOPRACIRes
                   select new ProcessOutput { SOPTemplateID = i.soptoptempid, valuematch = i.valuematch, JobTitleId = i.JobTitleId, DepartmentId = i.DepartmentId }).ToList();
                    ViewBag.res = res;
foreach (var item in secinf)
  {
    foreach (var data in (ViewBag.res))
        {
           ApplicationDbContext.RACIResChosenUser RACIResUser = new ApplicationDbContext.RACIResChosenUser();
           var sel = Request.Form[data.valuematch + "-RES"];

          Console.WriteLine("Dropdown res:");
          Console.WriteLine(sel);
          int onevalue = Convert.ToInt32(sel);

          var status = "Pending";

          RACIResUser.RACIResID = data.valuematch;
          RACIResUser.UserId = onevalue;
          RACIResUser.Status = status;

          RACIResUser.soptoptempid = data.SOPTemplateID;
          RACIResUser.InstanceId = getid;

          Console.WriteLine("data valuematch:");
          Console.WriteLine(RACIResUser.RACIResID);

          Console.WriteLine("data SOPTemplateID:");
          Console.WriteLine(data.SOPTemplateID);

          _context.RACIResUser.Add(RACIResUser);
          _context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
}
```

DB context:

```
public class RACIResChosenUser {
     [Key]
     public int RACIResChosenID { get; set; }
     public string RACIResID { get; set; }
     public string Status {get; set;}
     public string StatusComplete { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public string soptoptempid { get; set; }
     public string InstanceId { get; set; }
 }
 public DbSet<RACIResChosenUser> RACIResUser { get; set; }
```

cshtml:

```
@foreach(var data in (ViewBag.res)){
  var dropname = item.valuematch + "-RES";
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">  
       @Html.DropDownList(@dropname,ViewBag.selectlist as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })          
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you show your context class?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that it may be without further info.

This section:

```
ApplicationDbContext.RACIResChosenUser RACIResUser = new ApplicationDbContext.RACIResChosenUser();
```

1. It may be easier to keep your custom object lowercase in the scope it is in like raciResUser to just not have your instantiated object by the same case as your complex type of it.  It mostly likely may still work but that is a concern.
2. In your context you should have DbSet< RACIResUser>.  If not that is a problem.  But you probably do as usually you cannot even see the dbcontext.RACIResUser if it was not there.
3. Your 'Migrations' need to be up to date.  If you just added this POCO recently and you have it missing in a database or elsewhere you need to make a migration like:

   ```
   dotnet ef migrations Add (yourMigrationName)
   ```

   Else it has no idea about the changes.
4. Are you certain your connection string is pointing to a database you think you are going to?  Generally in ASP.NET Core you wire that up in the Startup.cs and it points to your appSettings.json.  Else if you make up the plain jane vanilla that inherits from DBContext you usually have a section like this:

   ```
      protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
      {

       if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {

          \#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;");
       }
   }
   ```

Where these settings would be matching what you want unless you want to override this with another location.